# How to compile clamav 0.98.3

Tags: clamav

I've never compiled a program until now I've only used Windows XP as my unique OS so I've never needed to learn how to type these commands in the Xubuntu 14.04 's terminal . I've passed 3 days reading faqs about how to deal with this problem but I've only been able to download clamav 0.98.3 from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/clamav/files/clamav/0.98.3/

As well the clamav's user know we can't only type $ sudo freshclam and automatically update our clamav 0.98.1 to 0.98.3 .

Please ,explain me step by step how can I update my antivirus . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linux malware is increasing (it's a good sign, because this means that Linux is becoming very popular!) and is a good practice to have a firewall enabled and a good antivirus to check the suspect files; this will also help to protect the other computers in your home/office.
**To update the ClamAV's engine+database and fix vulnerabilities/bugs execute this safe and easy procedure**:

1. Connect to the internet; you need a stable connection.
2. In a terminal (xterm is ok) execute `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. This will ensure that your system is up to date; the clamAV installer can behave differently if your base installation is old or if your source definitions are old.
3. Install the latest ClamAV from the Official Ubuntu repository, like any other Ubuntu software. **Do not install it from other, unsafe and non-specific sources, it can be dangerous**.
4. Execute `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-clamav/ppa` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade`. This should update the engine.
5. After all that, execute `sudo freshclam` to update the definitions. You **must** do that after an engine upgrade.

**If** you can't upgrade automatically your ClamAV installation, upgrade it from the source code or wait for an Ubuntu-specific release. I often suggest to compile the packages from sources because you often obtain a better result and you see what you are installing; please note that this type of installation is not always possible, you need the correct dependencies.
**To install ClamAV from sources** follow the [Official ClamAV Source-Install Guide](https://github.com/vrtadmin/clamav-faq/blob/master/faq/Installing.md); if you don't understand one point of the guide, feel free to ask by commenting under here and don't forget to press the UP arrow if I'm of any help.

Comment: That's my main point I don't understand or know how to follow the steps .You could explain me the steps ,but surely I also won't reach to update my clamav .At least ,Can you lead me with some basic explanation ?

Comment: Download the gzip file with the stable source code (clamav.net/download/sources/). 
Decompress the source in a new directory. 
Create a new group called clamav and a new user called clamav (from a GUI or from a terminal with groupadd). 
In a terminal browse the source code directory (use "cd SRCDIR") and execute "./configure". 
In the same directory execute "make", then execute "sudo make install". 
Execute "sudo ldconfig". 
Finish; update your clamAV virus database to stay protected. 
This procedure may vary from version to version, always read the INSTALL/README file.
Hope you solve. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need an antivirus.
2. When you run `sudo freshclam`, that should download and install the new database. I am guessing (since you don't really explain) that what worries you is this message:

   ```
   $ sudo freshclam 
   ClamAV update process started at Sun May 11 22:18:14 2014
   WARNING: Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!
   WARNING: Local version: 0.98.1 Recommended version: 0.98.3
   DON'T PANIC! Read http://www.clamav.net/support/faq
   ```

   First of all, that's just a warning. You can ignore it and the database will be updated correctly. If you insist on not ignoring it, you should do what it says and read http://www.clamav.net/support/faq which will take you to the upgrade instructions: https://github.com/vrtadmin/clamav-faq/blob/master/faq/Upgrading.md. Once there, you will note that the 1st suggestion is to simply wait until a package is available for your system.

   If you wait a while, Ubuntu will tell you to update to the latest clamav. If youcan't wait and insist on installing it, you will need to install from source. I cannot stress enough that this is just not worth it. You really don't need an antivirus scanner on Linux and you certainly don't need the bleeding edge version of its engine. If you insist on having one installed, just update it normally with `sudo freshclam` and leave it at that.

   Anyway, to install from source, you will need to follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/vrtadmin/clamav-faq/blob/master/faq/Installing.md).
3. You don't need an antivirus. Really, you just don't.