# How to update ClamAV engine from 0.98.1 to 0.98.4

Tags: upgrade, clamav

```
ClamAV update process started at Mon Sep 22 04:59:22 2014
WARNING: Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!
WARNING: Local version: 0.98.1 Recommended version: 0.98.4
DON'T PANIC! Read http://www.clamav.net/support/faq
main.cvd is up to date (version: 55, sigs: 2424225, f-level: 60, builder: neo)
daily.cld is up to date (version: 19413, sigs: 1148321, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
bytecode.cvd is up to date (version: 242, sigs: 46, f-level: 63, builder: dgoddard)
```

i try `$sudo freshclam` and sudo

`add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-clamav/ppa`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall clamav
clamscan -V
ClamAV 0.98.1/19413/Sun Sep 21 23:35:57 2014
```

but doesn't work

how to update ClamAV engine version from 0.98.1 to 0.98.4?

thx before

Comment: Is there any reason you need latest clamav? As your message shows you have databased uptated.

Comment: idk, but i get warning message "WARNING: Your ClamAV installation is OUTDATED!" how to fix thix warning message? thx before

Comment: `freshclam` is a tool to update the database of `clamav`, not the version of the binary (see `man freshclam`), so regardless of what doesn't work (you might want to be more specific in you question!) it won't solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Ubuntu repositories now have 0.98.5.  This answer is remaining here as legacy and evidence as to why this was +1'd and accepted.**

---

You can build and compile the source code of ClamAV as Karl's answer says, if you are worried about security vulnerabilities in PPA code.

Having said this, I've recently backported ClamAV 0.98.4 from Debian Unstable to Precise, Trusty, and Utopic in a PPA, without any changes, and that PPA [is located here](https://launchpad.net/~teward/+archive/ubuntu/clamav).  If you don't have any qualms using the package direct from Debian without changes, you can install `clamav 0.98.4` from my PPA by using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teward/clamav
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Note that you have to assume I won't be introducing vulnerabilities.  If you really want to see there's no differences between what's in Debian Unstable and my PPA, the changes files are available in the PPA itself.  (All I did was add a changelog entry for the Ubuntu upload and nothing more)

Comment: Note, this may be buggy, based on some of the Debian comments I've seen

Answer (score 0):

Building from source will definitely get you the latest version, see https://github.com/vrtadmin/clamav-faq/blob/master/faq/Installing.md and if you have further questions [How to compile clamav 0.98.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464506/how-to-compile-clamav-0-98-3).

There might be other ways, e.g. people providing builds of the latest version as packages (deb packages for Ubuntu or other formats which you have to convert). Installing those might be a more severe security vulnerability than just sticking with 0.98.1 - it's the sense of a distribution to provide a set of compatible packages tested in interaction.

Comment: any step by step with picture or video for building from souce it will help me alot thx anyway for respond my question :)

Comment: @Ivan there's no 'picture' or 'video' guide to compiling from source.  I can maybe backport Debian Unstable's 0.98.4+dfsg-2 package for Ubuntu, if you want... but as karl said, there's a possible security risk, there.  I always just copy Debian and leave it the same, and add a build entry for the Ubuntu release, but...

Comment: The instructions on the github.com site are excellent (in comparison to other build instructions). How should you be able to get further assistance efficiently after providing you with a video? At the end you have to type the failing instructions from the screen.. You don't want that! If you're using videos for instructions regularly I recommend you to stop.